# Set zoom level for display features in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, labeling

I´m using OpenStreetMap to show data of a specific region in Brasil. I would like to show the county names as soon I show the map, instead of in a higher level of zoom.

Comment: What would help people to answer this question would be more info about what software you're using here.  Other questions by you suggest it might be QGIS, but you really need to help people to help you.